# Accessing a variable that constantly changes part of its name, knowing only the unchanging part

Tags: javascript

I'm making a small autofilter script for a dating site.

To get the necessary information, i need to refer to the reactProps variable [image], part of the name of which (after the $ sign) is constantly changing (I am attaching a photo).

Is there any way to refer to a variable by that part of its name that does not change?

Comment: iterate the div's props and match the key/value you need

Comment: Please use text rather than images of code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh, my bad, i thought it would be easier to understand from the picture

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Where are those attributes coming from? Do you really need the name or do you need the value? There's likely an easier way of getting that data than reading some attributes off of an HTML Element.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I need the value. To be honest, i'm reading attributes off an HTML Element because i dont know another way to do it.

Comment: Iterate over the attribute names and use [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use this method, but, as people in the comments said, iterations also works.

Author of this answer is: @eccs0103 (Cant find him on the SO EN sadly)

```js
const object = {
  ["_reactFiber$dsadadasda"]: 0,
  ["__reactProps$dsadadasda"]: 1,
  ["reactSomethingElse$dsadadasda"]: 2,
};

function detectReactProps(dictionary) {
  const regex = /^\w*reactProps\$\w+$/;
  for (const property in dictionary) {
    if (regex.test(property)) return property;
  }
}

const keyReactProps = detectReactProps(object);

console.log(object[keyReactProps]); // read
object[keyReactProps] = 5; // write
```

Comment: Why would you use a regular expression?